# Is the world in Game of Thrones spherical or flat?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In extension to this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100921/what-is-to-the-west-of-westeros) about *Game of Thrones*, we know the map of Westeros and Essos which is in flat style.

Do the west of Westeros and the east of Essos connect?

Or is the map not completed yet?

[image: GoT Map]

Comment: Related to or answer given in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/does-the-song-of-ice-and-fire-take-place-in-a-hollow-world/4390?r=SearchResults#4390

Comment: Maps in reality are represented in some sort of flat projection, but that doesn't prove that Earth is flat. It was a common assumption for a long time.

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it be round?  If a paper map is your only evidence for thinking it is flat, this is flawed question.

Comment: Per the series finale, the map is not completed. One of the characters' goals is to add to the map. (Not to spoil anything)

Comment: The climate becomes colder close to the top of the map so it basically has to be round. Should be smaller than Earth though, not larger (assuming that Westeros is roughly the size of Great Britain)

Comment: Why can't it be both? Oh wait, because of geometry. *Thanks geometry.* Carry on.

Comment: @smcs: I can't find a reference immediately, but while Westeros is inspired by Great Britain and has a similar shape, it is much larger. Westeros is supposedly roughly the size of South America!

Comment: @Luciano: the [Maesters for Social Equality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OH1bZ0F3zVU) will tell you that this particular projection grossly inflates the perceived importance of Westeros. For all we know, Illyrio Mopatis hung it on infant Daenerys' bedroom wall, thus fuelling her Iron Throne obsession! It could be the map that destroyed Kings Landing!

Comment: @Luciano among whom? Pretty sure the ancients with enough intellectual curiosity to ask the question figured out the truth fairly quickly...

Comment: @JaredSmith many cultures believed the Earth was flat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Earth

Comment: 1. The sun rises and sets. 2. The North is colder.

Comment: @Luciano I stand corrected. I'm so used to people spouting the nonsensical "Columbus debunked that the Earth is flat" bit that I tend to forget there was a lot of human history before classical Greece.

Comment: @NathanCooper Something something perspective.

Comment: Using a map as evidence that the mapmaker thought the Earth is flat is singularly flawed logic. No, medieval people did NOT think the Earth is flat.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq The sun would still rise and set on a flat world rotating on an axis parallel to its surface, so that alone isn't evidence.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, and yet their seasons change in unpredictable way. And it thought it causes by magic. What if the North was colder because of magic of the Others? What if sunsets are caused by R'hlor riding his chariot in the sky?

Comment: While reasons submitted above could help support a round earth theory, there is no true way with what is given and there’s plenty of room for special phenomenon to describe temperature differences, sun rises, and the like. IMHO, the best empirical evidence may be the end scene with one of the characters sailing left (spoilers removed). In the scene, there is a horizon and while that does not universally prove anything, it may be the greatest characteristic to support a curved earth theory.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Answer from the show is **we don't know**.

No answer from the creator of the show and no hints are given in the show itself.

But Martin did answer this:

> Question: Is your world round. I mean if Dany traveled far enough east
>   couldnt she come to the other side of westeros?
>
> Martin: **Yes, the world is round.** Might be a little larger than ours,
>   though. I was thinking more like [Vance's Big Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Planet).... but don't hold
>   me to that - [westeros.org](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1206/)

Also in books, there was Elissa Farman (speculated that Arya's arc is inspired by her) who did a similar journey:

> Elissa always dreamed of sailing west to discover the strange and unknown lands never known to man before — which, again, was considered a laughable goal. Yet she made for a compelling enough captain to convince two other ships to join her daring journey beyond the edge of the world.
>   Changing her name to Alys Westhill, she set sail from Oldtown on Sun Chaser, with the Autumn Moon and the Lady Meredith beside her.
>
> Soon after, harsh storms took down the Autumn Moon, possibly with the
>   help of a kraken. But Sun Chaser and the Lady Meredith indeed managed
>   to sail farther west than anyone ever had before, discovering three
>   new islands which Captain Alys named Aegon, Visenya, and Rhaenys.
>
> Though Alys wanted to continue the journey, the Lady Meredith decided
>   to take the new spices and goods discovered on the islands and turn
>   back to Oldtown. So Sun Chaser's whereabouts fell off the map, along
>   with Captain Alys Westhill.
>
> Decades later, though, a famed captain and friend to the Targaryen
>   family reportedly spotted Sun Chaser in Asshai. And that's huge.
>
> Asshai is on the easternmost edge of the known map. So the most
>   logical explanation for Sun Chaser winding up there would be if it
>   actually did made it past the edge of the world to the west,
>   circumventing the globe to arrive on the other side of Essos. - [Mashable](https://mashable.com/article/game-of-thrones-arya-west-of-westeros/)

But we never get to know in books what happened to Elissa and if she really made this huge discovery then why she didn't publish it or maybe she was afraid as she did steal 3 eggs (supposedly Daenerys's dragon kids) and might have died before making any revelation, we don't know and might get more information in future books.